# Can I configure new user stories to be added to the backlog instead of the current sprint?

Tags: azure-devops

We have had several instances where new stories have been added to the backlog and then people are confused because the active sprint has new stories that haven't been refined - from the backlog view, adding a new Story always seems to add it to the current sprint iteration.

[image]

It seems a bad approach that new stories are added to a current iteration rather than the main backlog, is there a way to configure this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup default iteration for your team in Team configuration -> Default Iteration, it will set iteration value for work items created from Boards section and Backlogs section, but not for from Work Items section(because Work Items view is focused on all teams)

[image]

You can also setup and use template for it, it will allow you to customize multiple fields including 'Iteration path'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/work-item-template?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Comment: You can also set default Area Path for your team in the section Areas visible on the screen

Answer (score 1):

1.You need to ensure that you are in the current team with the backlog.

[image]
[image]

2.And you also need to check the default iteration of this specific team in project setting.

[image]